NFT example contract interaction
I've deployed the example: https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/create-token/anchor/programs/create-token/src/lib.rs
And been trying to interact with the contract to mint an NFT but failed. Any script example for reference? Thanks.
script I'm using now:
const anchor = require('@project-serum/anchor');
const { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, getAssociatedTokenAddress } = require('@solana/spl-token');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Path to the existing keypair file
const keypairPath = '/Users/.config/solana/id.json';  // Replace with your actual path

// Load the keypair from the file
const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairPath, 'utf-8')));
const payerKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

(async () => {
  try {
    // Set up provider (connected to devnet)
    const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", {
      commitment: "confirmed"
    });
    const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, new anchor.Wallet(payerKeypair), {});
    anchor.setProvider(provider);

    // Load the program ID
    const programId = new anchor.web3.PublicKey('8tKucvNwQt4jnMgQgZH26SxiV39XeHkjG1wDHzSCZi4H');

    // Load the IDL from local file
    const idlPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'target/idl/create_token.json');
    const idl = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(idlPath, 'utf8'));

    // Load the program
    const program = new anchor.Program(idl, programId, provider);

    // Create a new mint keypair
    const mintKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log(`Mint Address: ${mintKeypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`);

    // Derive the associated token account for the mint
    const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      payerKeypair.publicKey
    );
    console.log(`Associated Token Account: ${associatedTokenAccount.toBase58()}`);

    // Create metadata PDA (Program Derived Address) for the token
    const [metadataAccount] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from("metadata"),
        new anchor.web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s").toBuffer(),
        mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
      ],
      new anchor.web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s") // Metadata program ID
    );
    console.log(`Metadata Account Address: ${metadataAccount.toBase58()}`);

    // Specify accounts for the transaction
    const tx = await program.methods.createTokenMint(
      9, // Token decimals
      "ExampleToken", // Token name
      "EXT", // Token symbol
      "https://example.com/token-metadata.json" // Token URI
    )
    .accounts({
      payer: payerKeypair.publicKey,
      metadata_account: metadataAccount,
      mint_account: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      token_metadata_program: new anchor.web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"),
      token_program: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      system_program: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY
    })
    .signers([payerKeypair, mintKeypair]) // Mint account and payer must sign
    .rpc();

    console.log('Token minted successfully! Transaction ID:', tx);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error minting token:', error);
  }
})();



what versions of the CLI suite are you running and also what versions of the crates are you using? Could you also add the error you are encountering?

anchor-cli 0.30.1, error: Error minting token: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')

everything looks okay from going through it. Could you update your anchor package to use one that matches the CLI @coral-xyz/anchor - 0.30.1

still getting the same error after updating. were you able to run the script successfully and mint?
